# check next not disabled radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a bunch of radio buttons, and depending on the choices of other radio buttons, some of radio's are disabled. The problem is that they the disabled ones remain checked. It's hard to explain this and it's not something I can show in code, because it's just a bunch of garbage and experiments.

So anyway, my question is, how do you find the first not disabled radio button in a radio button group (same name)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(':radio:not(:disabled):first')
```

without first it will find all not disabled radios.

Answer (score 4):

You can find all radiobuttons with `:radio`

You can reduce that result with `:not`

You can target all disabled elements with `:disabled`

You can return the first element from the given set with `:first`

```
$('input:radio:not(:disabled):first')
```

If you want to find out which radiobutton is checked, disregarding any disabled ones, you may want to do something like

```
$('input:radio:checked:not(:disabled)')
```

Comment: this would implicitly use the universal selector `*`, pretty bad. Better full qualify it by prepending `input` = `'input:radio:not(:disabled)'`